# Valid values for DMA_CNDTRx NDT field

Tags: stm32, dma

Can DMA_CNDTRx NDT be read zero when DMA is enabled in cyclic mode?

NDT, which is the counter, is automatically reloaded to initial settings when it reaches 0 but I cannot find in the reference manual any clear indication that it cannot be ever read 0.

I'm currently working on STM32L4A6 but the dma peripheral should be the same for most Fx.

I've worked with several dma but I have always ignored that fact.

Thanks

Comment: You usually shouldn't read these DMA counter registers because of possible race conditions. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Count the remaining data in DMA buffer while the UART is idle. I don't think there is any race condition in accessing these register, why you say so?

Comment: Because the counter might change right after reading it, possibly before reading other DMA status registers (or other way round). Whether this is bad or not depends on what you do with the value

Comment: That is irrelevant, in this specific case.